# render trajectory of particle in forcefield using GLSL shader

Tags: opengl, physics, geometry-shader, tessellation

I want to visualize flow of particles in some forcefield e.g. electromagetic, gravitional or potential flow in fluid ([streamlines](http://www.apollocanard.com/index_htm_files/184.jpg));

I was thinking to use [Geometry Shader](https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Geometry-Shader) which would look like this (not tested, just sketch):

```
#version 330 core
layout (points) in;
layout (line_strip, max_vertices = 64) out;

uniform float dt; 

vec3 getForce(in vec3 pos){ /* ... don't care now ... */ }

void main() {
    vec3 pos = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    for( int i=0; i<64; i++ ){
        pos += getForce(pos) * dt; // it's actually velocity field but who cares
        gl_Position = pos;
        EmitVertex();
    }
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

However, I read that [Geometry shaders are very slow](http://www.joshbarczak.com/blog/?p=667) (I did not yet tested). So I wonder if it would be helpful in this situation?

Or would [Tesselation shaders](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation) or [Compute shaders](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Compute_Shader) be suitable for this job and achieving better performance?.

**background:** I have experience with vertex-shaders, fragment-shaders, OpenCL ... but I have never tried geometry-,tesselation- nor compute-shaders.

---

EDIT: there is my simple example implementation using geometry shader in 2D
https://github.com/ProkopHapala/SimpleSimulationEngine/blob/ca16b6f8d72864a8a572ed2a21ded99c5c2cc3e4/cpp/sketches_SDL/OGL3/test_GeometryShader.cpp

which plots this (for velocity field defined by dipole):
[image]

Comment: The question seems unclear. Do you wish to see the path of one or more particles, as in rendering the full curve from start to finish?

Comment: yes, I want to provide as input vertex attributes starting position (and eventually also initial velocity), and the shader should expand it to full path (some number N of iterations of the equation of motion). So if my input vertex buffer (mesh) is composed of 1000 points, I want to draw 1000 curves  each with N points.